deprecated functions in the solana web3.js : sendAndConfirmTransaction
I just wanted to know if sendAndConfirmTransaction is working fine as most of the internal functions used seem deprecated. I am trying to send a transaction and getting a few blockers, just wanted to know if the function is working as it should.
[![code picture][1]][1]
const signature = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, signers, sendOptions);

in this The signature '(transaction: any, signersOrOptions: any, options: any): Promise<any>' of 'connection.sendTransaction' is deprecated.


status = (await connection.confirmTransaction({
      abortSignal: options?.abortSignal,
      signature: signature,
      blockhash: transaction.recentBlockhash,
      lastValidBlockHeight: transaction.lastValidBlockHeight
    }, options && options.commitment)).value;

In this code The signature '(strategy: any, commitment: any): Promise<any>' of 'connection.confirmTransaction' is deprecated.ts(6387)
index.browser.cjs.js(5670, 7): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/f9s9m.png


The code certainly works, but the calls it's using might be removed in the future, which is why you're getting the "deprecated" warning.
Since sendAndConfirmTransaction isn't marked deprecated, however, it will likely be updated to use the non-deprecated functions. Feel free to send in a PR at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js if you want to update it!
